# Obtaining the public share link from Fusion Teams Doc, via forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a question for the Autodesk Forge developers. Is it possible to obtain the public share url (as attached) for a file via the forge API? If it was provided a file name, could it search all documents inside a team hub and find the file, and return the share url? If yes what would the script look like to do this? I have very limited understanding of javascript and full stack web development, but this would save us a lot of time. [Share URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzM1C.png) Another time saver would be changing the file name. If someone already has a script to do that, it would be awesome.

I have tried various forge tutorials, but it's a bit over my head.

Answer (score 0):

The share URL you show in the screenshot is a feature of the application, not the Autodesk Platform Services (formerly Forge).

You could build a similar sharing functionality yourself if you wanted to, but as you correctly pointed out, that would require some development experience. If you do decide to give it a shot, here's some links to get you started:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/ - this endpoint can be used to search and filter  content of a specific folder and all its subfolders. This could be used to search for a specific file in an entire project.
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signed-POST/ - this endpoint creates a short-lived, "pre-signed" URL that anybody can use to read and/or write files from/to your storage. That's basically your share URL.